# How to "enable" True Color Support and Nerd Fonts in Arch Linux Console

Tags: arch-linux, colors, console

*From now on, every time I say "console" I refer to the console you must use in Arch Linux if a desktop environment is not yet installed.*

I want to "enable" [True Color Support](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) in the console so that I can install and use the [browsh](https://www.brow.sh/) text-based web browser in the console.

I also want to install fonts that have programming ligatures such as [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) and [Cascadia Code](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code) on the console. And I want to install [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/), specifically Fira Code.

How do you do that without installing a desktop environment to see [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) and [True Color](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) on the console?

Comment: I see a downvote to my question. And I would like to know why that was applied; what can I do to improve.

Comment: Hello Jimmy, we do not process this kind of information = who voted up/down, I see a perfectly formulated question now after the latest edit. This however does not prevent anyone else from voting as they see fit. I will vote your question up now to "revert" it. Cheers and good luck on our site.

Comment: @JimmyZeng you are an honorable member of the FOSS community. I will you had gotten a good answer. If you ever find a solution, or alternative, please tag me.
☮️❤️☸️☯️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the kernel implemented tty, then it simply doesn't support those functionalities.

But you can get a Terminal Emulator which supports them without installing a full desktop environment, or even without any Wayland compositor or X Server

Comment: How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

[fbterm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fbterm)

> (Frame buffer terminal emulator) is standalone replacement of Linux
> kernel terminal that can function outside of graphical environments

.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the best answer so far, can you elaborate more, such as showing how to use it and some of the features it contains?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't, there are several terminal emulators that are capable of displaying true color on the linux terminal, but most of them don't work with current versions of the kernel, and of those that do are riddled with bugs, further, by definition they prevent other graphical console applications from working.

Of particular relevance to your intention to use browsh, none support the use of the mouse, and browsh does not support the use of the keyboard.

The blocking of other graphical console applications is something that needs to be addressed in the kernel, while the mouse could probably be fixed by a console application. The primary problem is that the kernel developers don't want the console to improve (in fact they have allowed it to degrade significantly in functionality despite Linus' lies about not breaking userspace) because they can't be bothered maintaining it.

Sadly, anything other than the most basic TTY functionality is considered legacy because of a kind of self-fulfilling prophecy that "nobody uses the console anymore" - which of course is true, since nearly nothing useful works on the console anymore.

Give up. The kernel maintainers already have, and that is not likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

KMSCON is another alternative that works very well. I've just installed it, and now all the consoles can work with nerdfonts
[image: kmscon]

Here some info to use it in Arch:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KMSCON